# Making a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

How would I make this into a method that accepts an object of type NSArray called *objects* and can be called from different view controllers such as the last method called *saveContext*?

```
//Save to Core Data

CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
LeanMessage *message = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LeanMessage" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];

for (NSDictionary *lean in objects)
{        
    [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"objectId"] forKey:@"objectId"];
    [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"senderId"] forKey:@"senderId"];
    [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"recipientId"] forKey:@"recipientId"];
    [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"messageBody"] forKey:@"body"];
    [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"timestamp"] forKey:@"timestamp"];    
}

[coreDataStack saveContext];
```

Answer (score 0):

`.h` file

```
@interface ...

...
- (void)myMethod: (NSArray *)objects;

@end
```

.`m` file

```
- (void)myMethod: (NSArray *)objects
{
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    LeanMessage *message = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LeanMessage" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];

    for (NSDictionary *lean in objects){
        [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"objectId"] forKey:@"objectId"];
        [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"senderId"] forKey:@"senderId"];
        [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"recipientId"] forKey:@"recipientId"];
        [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"messageBody"] forKey:@"body"];
        [message setValue:[lean objectForKey:@"timestamp"] forKey:@"timestamp"];
    }

    [coreDataStack saveContext];
}
```

if you want to access it from another class and if your current class's name is `myClass`, in the class you want to access it, just do the following:

```
NSArray *anotherArray = ...
myClass *thisClass = [[myClass alloc] init];
[thisClass myMethod:anotherArray];
```

Hope this answers your question. :)

Comment: Where's the parameter variable? And you need to pass a value when you call `myMethod:`.

Comment: You don't use `myArray`. And what is `objects`?

Comment: Your edit is worse. The parameter is named `message`. You also have a local variable named `message`. And you have an undeclared variable in your loop named `objects`. Please proof read.

Comment: Also to use the method from a different class, you need to declare the method in the interface (.h) file.